# Вложенное наследование в Jade

Tags: jade

Доброго времени!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли вложенное наследование в Jade?

Проблема такая:
Файл layout представляет собой основную разметку. В нем определен блок main, в который будет вставляться необходимый контент:

layout.jade

```
...код
...код
   block main
...код
...код
```

Файл item содержит разметку самостоятельного структурного блока, в нем есть `block content`.

item.jade

```
...код
...код
   block content
...код
...код
```

В главном файле через `extends` подключается layout.jade, в его блок `main` вставляется item.jade. Соответственно в блок `content` также вставляется какой-то контент.

index.jade

```
extends layout
block main
    include header
    extends item
    block content
        p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    include footer
```

В скомпилированном файле остается только блок `item` с абзацем `Lorem ipsum`, а `layout`, `header` и `footer` отсутствуют.
Возможно, я допускаю ошибку в синтаксисе? Или вложенное наследование невозможно?

Благодарю за ответы!

Comment: Что самое обидное, в документации вскользь говорится, что вы можете использовать вложенное расширение, но примеров нет :(

Comment: Теперь поддерживается директивой `extends`. Про само вложенное наследование можно почитать [тут](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html).